# Why are my python imports not found after installed with pip?

Tags: python, pip

I am creating an API using python and I am trying to use imports such as Flask but I am getting the following error:

```
Import "flask" could not be resolved from source
```

However, I have installed all of these using pip, and here is the confirmation:

[image]

As you can see, all imports have the `Requirement already satisfied` status. Does anyone know why it can't be found in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot your IDE is running Python 3.8.9 and you installed `flask` in your Python 3.9 environment hence it is unable to find it. Make sure the Python versions match when running your IDE.

Comment: How do I install them in Python 3.9?

Comment: `python3.9 -m pip install ...`

Comment: This just opens a python shell, no install command is run?

Comment: sorry I put in an extra space after the `-` try the edited command now

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I am still getting that issue

Comment: update your post with the new information/attempt because it sounds like you are still using the wrong version in your IDE

Comment: Since he is using python 3.8, he should try `python3.8 -m pip install ...`

Comment: yes but it depends what version he wants to use, as I mention in my answer the IDE and where he installs it need to match in version